# Проблема области видимости переменной ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть код

```
j = 0
10.times do |i|
  if @days[k].mday == reservs_room[j][0].mday then
    colspan = reservs_room[j][1]*2
    j += 1
  else
    colspan = 1 
  end
end
```

Кричит и ругается

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Меняю на

```
10.times do |i|
  if @days[k].mday == reservs_room[0][0].mday then
    colspan = reservs_room[0][1]*2
  else
    colspan = 1 
  end
end
```

и все хорошо, в чем дело?

Полный пример:

```
    @days = Array.new(daysCount)
    i = 0; (-2..daysCount - 3).map {|n| @days[i] = Time.now + n.day; i += 1;}

    @reserv_cols = Array.new(@rooms.length)

    @rooms.each_index do |row_index|
      @reserv_cols[row_index] = []
      k = 0

      reservs_room = [[(Time.now), 3], [(Time.now+5.day), 5]]
      sum_day_reserv = 8

      j = 0
      num = 2*daysCount-1-sum_day_reserv*2
      num.times do |i|

        if @days[k].mday == reservs_room[j][0].mday then
          colspan = reservs_room[j][1]*2
          j += 1
        else
          colspan = 1 
        end

        @reserv_cols[row_index].push([@days[k], colspan])
        if i.odd? then k += 1 end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Пример невозможно проверить. Можете привести минимальный **самодостаточный** пример, который иллюстрирует проблему?

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что в массиве `reservs_room` - меньше 10 элементов.

Comment: Может быть, как проверить пустой ли элемент массива?

Comment: В полном примере j меняется. Ошибка возникает из-за этого.
Проверить пустоту массива можно всё теми же стандартными `blank?`, `present?`, `any?`.
Если хочешь чтобы твой код был читаемым и понятным - лучше использовать [стайлгайды](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). В этой мешанине очень трудно было что-то разобрать.

Comment: Почему рельсисты отказываются учить язык, на котором пишут? `any?` никогда не проверял массив на пустоту.

Answer (score 1):

У вас массив `reservs_room` имеет размер равный `2`-м:

```
reservs_room = [[(Time.now), 3], [(Time.now+5.day), 5]]
```

а возможные значения для `j` с `0` до `2*daysCount-1-sum_day_reserv*2`, ну скажем кол-во дней у вас `16`, сумма `8` и при значении `j` равным `2-м` вы получаете вот тут:

```
reservs_room[j]
```

значение `nil`.